# Dialog showed as a div after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a single page CRUD.
Right now, I faced some errors with the show function.

An example of the application can be found here:
http://tryoutcreation.herokuapp.com/

It appears to work alright.
After creation, the show function works fine if the page is not refreshed.

However, if it is refreshed, the dialog stops working as a dialog and just shows as a div.

You can try it by creating a user and clicking the show function. Then try refreshing the page, the same div will just be shown on the page instead of as a dialog.

The source can be found here:
https://github.com/frozzie/ModalCrud

Related codes:

The dialog is the show-form.

```
  <tr id = "<%= dom_id user%>">
<td><%= user.user_name %></td>
<td><%= user.email %></td>
<td><%= user.password %></td>
<td><%= user.account_type %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', user, :remote=>true%></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user), :remote => true %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :remote => true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</td> 
<div id = "show-form" title="User Information">
  <p>
  <b>User name:</b>
    <%= user.user_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Email:</b>
    <%= user.email %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <b>Password:</b>
    <%= user.password %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Account type:</b>
    <%= user.account_type %>
 </p>
</div>
</tr>
```

It should only be opened when the show button is clicked.
    $("#show-form").dialog( "open" );

This is the dialog.

```
   $( "#show-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    })
```

Any ideas on why it happened would be appreciated.

Comment: seems like you have multiple elements `#show form` for one

Comment: When you create the page, do you generate the form div with the content or do you fill the empty form live?

Comment: Yes i do have multiple elements for #show-form, would that be the problem?

Comment: hmm, not sure what you mean by filling the empty form live.

Comment: I think the issue is show form keeps showing the first element. Lemme look into it.

Comment: IDs should be unique. All your forms have an id of `show-form`. By filling the empty form live, i meant that on click, you copy the data from your table row to the unique show-form and then show it. But if you want to have multiple divs with the data already in it (filled by your server), then make sure they are hidden and that you can select them in a unique matter (not multiple divs with the same id)

Comment: I see. So there was no need for multiple divs in the first place. I will try that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has less to do with your js than it does your php.

Remove this from your code:

```
      <div id = "show-form" title="User Information">
        <p>
        <b>User name:</b>
        <%= user.user_name %>
        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Email:</b>
        <%= user.email %>
        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Password:</b>
        <%= user.password %>
        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Account type:</b>
        <%= user.account_type %>
        </p>
        </div>
```

then look to output the users information correctly. Don't just output this at the top of the page.

```
        <tr id = "<%= dom_id user%>">
            <td><%= user.user_name %></td>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= user.password %></td>
            <td><%= user.account_type %></td>
            <td class="click_me" data-id="<%= dom_id user%>"><%= link_to 'Show', user, :remote=>true%></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user), :remote => true %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :remote => true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr  style="display: none;" class="hidden_<%= dom_id user%>">
        <td colspan="8">

        <div class = "show-form" title="User Information">
        <p>
        <b>User name:</b>
        <%= user.user_name %>
        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Email:</b>
        <%= user.email %>
        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Password:</b>
        <%= user.password %>
        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Account type:</b>
        <%= user.account_type %>
        </p>
        </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

now,

```
$('td').on('click','.click_me', function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $('.hidden_'+id).slideToggle();
});
```

This isn't perfect... lol by any means, but at least you can work with it hopefully.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I get the idea of hiding the divs but I tried out another method without having divs for each user.